# Add tuple2 values in JavaPairDStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a `JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<Double, Double>>` with values,

```
(ADBE,(1.1,1.2))
(MSFT,(3.2,1.2))
```

I want tuple values to be added together and converted to `JavaPairDStream<String,Double>` as

```
(ADBE,(2.3))
(MSFT,(4.4))
```

How can I achieve this in Java Spark streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that pairs is the JavaPairDStream> stream:

```
    JavaPairDStream<String,Double> sd = pairs.mapValues((Function<Tuple2<Double, Double>, 
    Double>) v1 -> v1._1 + v1._2);
```

this will transform the stream to add the two double values to one.